# Como crear un bwplot en lattice

Tags: r, rstudio

Apenas estoy ampezando mi aventura con R y aun tengo muchas dudas.
Me gustaria crear un `bwplot` de los 5 subsets que tengo pero no tengo idea como hacerlo. Quiero comparar variables `RealInv` y `RealGNP`.

Es lo que hay por el momento y necesito visualizarlo de alguna forma en lattice:

```
library(lattice)
n<- 4
dfchunk <- split(Investment, factor(sort(rank(row.names(Investment))%%n)))
dfchunk
```

Estos son los datos de partida:

```
Investment <- structure(list(GNP = c(596.7, 637.7, 691.1, 756, 799.6, 873.4 ), Investment = c(90.9, 97.4, 113.5, 125.7, 122.8, 133.3), Price = c(0.7167, 0.7277, 0.7436, 0.7676, 0.7906, 0.8254), Interest = c(3.23, 3.55, 4.04, 4.5, 4.19, 5.16), RealGNP = c(832.565927166178, 876.322660436993, 929.397525551372, 984.887962480459, 1011.38375917025, 1058.15362248607 ), RealInv = c(126.83131017162, 133.84636526041, 152.635825712749, 163.757165190203, 155.325069567417, 161.497455779016),RealInt = c(NA, 2.01518766568997, 1.85503366772021, 1.27245831091986, 1.19364773319437, 0.758279787503155)), .Names = c("GNP", "Investment", "Price", "Interest", "RealGNP", "RealInv", "RealInt"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Estare agradecida por cualquier indicacion

Comment: Hola Kas, bienvenida. Para poder ayudarte nos serviría conocer la estructura de los datos. Una forma fácil es hacer `dput(head(datos))` en la consola de R y pegar el resultado (donde `datos` son los datos con los que estás trabajando). Serán las primeras 10 filas de tu estructura de datos. El código que agregas no aporta mucho, sería mejor que nos mostraras tus intentos directamente con `bwplot()`. De paso: no creo que necesites hacer el subset antes de graficar, el "chiste" de lattice es que es muy bueno para hacer los subsets directamente en la sintaxis del gráfico usando el símbolo `|`.

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias mpaladio por tu respuesta. Los datos con los que estoy trabajando son estos: structure(list(GNP = c(596.7, 637.7, 691.1, 756, 799.6, 873.4
), Investment = c(90.9, 97.4, 113.5, 125.7, 122.8, 133.3), Price = c(0.7167, 
0.7277, 0.7436, 0.7676, 0.7906, 0.8254), Interest = c(3.23, 3.55, 
4.04, 4.5, 4.19, 5.16), RealGNP = c(832.565927166178, 876.322660436993, 
929.397525551372, 984.887962480459, 1011.38375917025, 1058.15362248607
), RealInv = c(126.83131017162, 133.84636526041, 152.635825712749, 
163.757165190203, 155.325069567417, 161.497455779016),

Comment: RealInt = c(NA, 
2.01518766568997, 1.85503366772021, 1.27245831091986, 1.19364773319437, 
0.758279787503155)), .Names = c("GNP", "Investment", "Price", 
"Interest", "RealGNP", "RealInv", "RealInt"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")     Mis intentos con bwplot por el momento no han dado muchos frutos: bwplot(RealGNP ~ RealInv, data=Investment, xlab="Real Investment") Por eso pense que a lo mejor reducir las observaciones podria hacer la visualisacion mas clara.

Comment: Hola Kas, te sugiero que agregues el `dput()` en la pregunta y el código con el que lo intentaste en la pregunta. En tus datos sólo hay variables continuas. Quizás ese sea problema, un boxplot se usa para visualizar la distribución de una variable continua en diferentes niveles de una variable categórica, en R un factor.  Si especificás la fórmula de con dos variables del tipo `numeric` en  `bwplot()` no va a funcionar. La que está del lado izquierdo debe ser del tipo `factor()`. Podés usar `as.factor(RealInv)` para convertirla.

Answer (score 1):

Con ggplot se puede hacer así

```
Investment <- structure(list(GNP = c(596.7, 637.7, 691.1, 756, 799.6, 873.4 ), Investment = c(90.9, 97.4, 113.5, 125.7, 122.8, 133.3), Price = c(0.7167, 0.7277, 0.7436, 0.7676, 0.7906, 0.8254), Interest = c(3.23, 3.55, 4.04, 4.5, 4.19, 5.16), RealGNP = c(832.565927166178, 876.322660436993, 929.397525551372, 984.887962480459, 1011.38375917025, 1058.15362248607 ), RealInv = c(126.83131017162, 133.84636526041, 152.635825712749, 163.757165190203, 155.325069567417, 161.497455779016),RealInt = c(NA, 2.01518766568997, 1.85503366772021, 1.27245831091986, 1.19364773319437, 0.758279787503155)), .Names = c("GNP", "Investment", "Price", "Interest", "RealGNP", "RealInv", "RealInt"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)                  #Carga librería de gráficos y manipulación. 
Investment %>%                      #llamo a los datos
  select(RealGNP, RealInv) %>%      #Selecciono las columnas que me interesan
  gather() %>%                      #Las paso a formato largo
  ggplot(aes(x=key, y=value)) +     #Mapeo las variables a los ejes.
  geom_boxplot()                    #Especifico el tipo de gráfico.
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te lo comentó mpaladino en sus comentarios los `boxplot` sirven para comparar variables categóricas, discretas o `Factor`, como quieras llamarlas. Por lo que comentas, los que buscas es comparar `RealInv` con `RealGNP`, de manera que deberías crear estas dos categorías. Por ejemplo si tomáramos tu ejemplo completo, podrías hacer esto:

```
Investment <- structure(list(GNP = c(596.7, 637.7, 691.1, 756, 799.6, 873.4 ), Investment = c(90.9, 97.4, 113.5, 125.7, 122.8, 133.3), Price = c(0.7167, 0.7277, 0.7436, 0.7676, 0.7906, 0.8254), Interest = c(3.23, 3.55, 4.04, 4.5, 4.19, 5.16), RealGNP = c(832.565927166178, 876.322660436993, 929.397525551372, 984.887962480459, 1011.38375917025, 1058.15362248607 ), RealInv = c(126.83131017162, 133.84636526041, 152.635825712749, 163.757165190203, 155.325069567417, 161.497455779016),RealInt = c(NA, 2.01518766568997, 1.85503366772021, 1.27245831091986, 1.19364773319437, 0.758279787503155)), .Names = c("GNP", "Investment", "Price", "Interest", "RealGNP", "RealInv", "RealInt"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df <- data.frame(item=c(rep("RealGNP",times=nrow(Investment)), rep("RealInv",times=nrow(Investment))),
                 valor=c(Investment$RealGNP,Investment$RealInv))
```

Para graficar hemos creado un nuevo `data.frame` con la siguiente estructura:

```
      item     valor
1  RealGNP  832.5659
2  RealGNP  876.3227
3  RealGNP  929.3975
4  RealGNP  984.8880
5  RealGNP 1011.3838
6  RealGNP 1058.1536
7  RealInv  126.8313
8  RealInv  133.8464
9  RealInv  152.6358
10 RealInv  163.7572
11 RealInv  155.3251
12 RealInv  161.4975
```

Ahora, graficamos estos valores:

```
bwplot(valor ~ item, data=df)
```

Y la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También lo puedes aplicar a tus `chunks` de datos, en definitiva no son más que otros `data.frames` pero lo que tienes que tener en cuenta, que en tu ejemplo `dfchunk` es una lista de `data.frames`, por lo que debería `plotear` cada uno accediendo por índice, por ejemplo:

```
chunk <- dfchunk[[2]]
df <- data.frame(item=c(rep("RealGNP",times=nrow(chunk)), rep("RealInv",times=nrow(chunk))),
                 valor=c(chunk$RealGNP,chunk$RealInv))

bwplot(valor ~ item, data=df)
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Claro, en realidad el factor era el nombre de columna. La solución es correcta y la que pedía Kas. Abajo agredo otra con `ggplot` que no era lo que pedían, pero...